# Performance and caching: AEM QueryBuilder API vs AEM GraphQL API?

Tags: aem-6

Can someone brief me and help me decide which one to go with between AEM QueryBuilder Vs AEM GraphQL API?

I see that you have option of persistent queries in GraphQL do we have any caching options in QueryBuilder? How can we leverage it to the fullest?

Would using QueryBuilder against GraphQL mean drop in performance or it should be fine to use the same?

In which cases would one suit better over other can you have a brief about it? I know that when you have sorting, pagination, etc operations you can't use GraphQL but what about all the other scenarios, would I have issues in performance or any advantage like caching over QueryBuilder if I use GQL or it would almost be the same?

Answer (score 0):

As per Adobe's documentation you should use GraphQL when you're trying to expose data from Content Fragments. Network calls to persistent GraphQL queries are cached as these are GET calls. However if there are huge number of Content Fragments in the system for instance > 50000, please avoid using GraphQL queries as these might be run extremely slow.